# AWS PHP SDK: Caching SQS getQueueUrl

Tags: php, caching, sdk, amazon-sqs

I have just started using `Amazon SQS`.

In order to make a request I must first call `$sqs->GetQueueURL(...)` to retreive the full URL of my queue.

ie: https://sqs.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXX/QUEUENAME

As far as I can tell, I need to make this request every time before calling an operation on the queue (ie: `ReceiveMessage` or `SendMessage`).

Is there an inbuilt support for `AWS PHP SDK` to cache these URLs? Does it do it automatically?

I can't seem to find any detail on what (if any) caching is happening by default.

Answer (score 3):

you do dont have to pull the queue url each time as it does not change.

go to sqs consule, and check all your queues. then copy the url you need, and use it.